# Vbscript Logic Missing - Looking for Help to read remote text file with which has current date as text in the file

Tags: vbscript

I have an application which will write below log file automatically with the name of “CoreAPP.txt“

**Sample of “CoreAPP.txt“:**

```
[10/31/2012 19:53:41:889 SWAP INF] {hap=CB2:app=Internet Explorer_b1 6.0.3790.3959:tid=22C0:usr=B9D327}
Elapsed time for upload: 0.718 seconds


[10/31/2012 19:53:42:639 SWAP INF] {hap=CB2:app=Internet Explorer_b1 6.0.3790.3959:tid=22C0:usr=V9V327}
Elapsed time for launch: 3.250 seconds


[10/31/2012 19:56:37:815 ???? INF] {tid=4004:usr=V47235}
An error occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A


[10/31/2012 19:56:37:846 ???? INF] {tid=4004}
An error occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A



[10/31/2012 10:45:00:576 ???? INF] {tid=1650}
An error occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A
ElapR
The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL 'RTSP://SRVW23E:554/V1321_BDP_V1_R1_SB/V1321_BDP_C1_P2PM_SS.sft' (rc 1690900A-00002002, 

original rc 1690900A-00002002).


[10/31/2012 00:29:59:843 OSDF ERR] {tid=1464}
The Application Virtualization Client could not parse the OSD file 'C:\SoftCache\SoftGrid Client\OSD Cache\edCc4305-3f6C-4dcc-3d70-404eb8bd97d8.osd'. 

Reason: XML parsing failure (rc 00000A25-00000002)

[10/31/2012 08:24:35:869 ???? ERR] {tid=336C:usr=t405230}
corrupt cp file detected ('V:\V1321_BDP\osguard.cp'). osguard cp file, NO CORRECTIVE ACTION TAKEN


[10/31/2012 22:16:39:240 JGSW ERR] {hap=1C82:app=bDP c15 E2AM SS 1.0:tid=3D58}
The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL 'RTSP://PSWQAPP1:554/V14678993_BDP_C15_E2AM_SS/V14678993_BDP_C15_E2AM_SS.sft' (rc 

1690900A-00002002, original rc 1690900A-00002002).


[10/31/2012 22:16:39:240 SWAP ERR] {hap=1C82:app=bDP c15 E2AM SS 1.0:tid=3D58}
The client was unable to connect to an Application Virtualization Server (rc 1690900A-00002002)


[10/31/2012 22:17:09:163 AMGR ERR] {tid=4F54}
The specified application name (Application Integration) is ambiguous. Some potential matches:
Application Integration 7.0.1756.1756
Application Integration 9.2.2373.2373


[10/31/2012 22:17:09:163 AMGR ERR] {tid=4F54}
The Application Virtualization Client cannot open Application Integration

[10/31/2012 00:03:14:313 SWAP WRN] {tid=507C:usr=N28712}
Could not load OSD file \\PSWQAPP1\Content\D1311_bDP_Adobe_Reader_9.3.3\D1311_bDP_Adobe_Reader 9.3.3.osd


[10/31/2012 00:03:14:313 AMGR INF] {tid=507C:usr=i435145}
The app manager could not create an application from '\\PSWQAPP1\Content\D1311_bDP_Adob_dobe_Reader_9.3.3\D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe Reader 9.3.3.osd' (rc 

0C405664-00000002).


====
[10/31/2012 13:35:16:987 JGSW ERR] {hap=1:app=Abaculus 1.0.0.1:tid=14C8:usr=R3R7DF42}
The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL 'RTSP:%SFT_SRV

%:554/D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe_Abaculus_15_01/D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe_Abaculus_15_01.sft' (rc 19D02E0A-10000002, original rc 19D02E0A-10000002).


[10/31/2012 13:35:47:998 SWAP ERR] {hap=2:app=AboutPI-SDK 1.3.0.26:tid=1568:usr=I337721}
Could not load app


[10/31/2012 19:56:37:862 SWAP INF] {hap=CB3:app=Adobe Reader X 10.0.1.434:tid=4004:usr=V47235}
Elapsed time for upload: 0.609 seconds


[10/31/2012 19:56:38:393 SWAP INF] {hap=CB3:app=Adobe Reader X 10.0.1.434:tid=4004:usr=V47236}
Elapsed time for launch: 1.187 seconds


[10/31/2012 19:56:57:487 SWAP INF] {hap=CB3:app=Adobe Reader X 10.0.1.434:tid=4004:usr=V47234}
App shut down


[10/31/2012 20:01:40:745 ???? INF] {tid=327C:usr=V42235}
An error occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A


[10/31/2012 20:01:40:776 ???? INF] {tid=327C}
An error occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A


[10/31/2012 20:01:40:776 SWAP INF] {hap=CB4:app=Adobe Reader X 10.0.1.434:tid=327C:usr=V422357235}
Elapsed time for upload: 0.609 seconds


[11/01/2012 16:48:44:157 SWAP INF] {hap=11A4:app=Lotus Notes_b1 6.5.40.5086:tid=361C:usr=A422353001}
Elapsed time for launch: 5.219 seconds


[11/01/2012 16:50:21:003 ???? INF] {tid=32D8:usr=W8WS83}
An error occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A


[11/01/2012 16:50:21:066 ???? INF] {tid=32D8}
An error occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A


[11/01/2012 16:50:21:082 SWAP INF] {hap=11A5:app=Adobe Reader X 10.0.1.434:tid=32D8:usr=W8WS83}
Elapsed time for upload: 0.703 seconds


[11/01/2012 16:50:22:503 SWAP INF] {hap=11A5:app=Adobe Reader X 10.0.1.434:tid=32D8:usr=W8WS83}
Elapsed time for launch: 2.218 seconds


[11/01/2012 16:50:50:395 SWAP INF] {hap=11A5:app=Adobe Reader X 10.0.1.434:tid=32D8:usr=A422353001}
App shut down


[11/01/2012 16:53:24:367 ???? INF] {tid=1F80:usr=t405230}
An error occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A


[11/01/2012 16:53:24:383 ???? INF] {tid=1F80}
An error occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A


[11/01/2012 16:53:24:383 SWAP INF] {hap=11A6:app=Show Desktop 1.0:tid=1F80:usr=A422353001}
Elapsed time for upload: 0.531 seconds


[11/01/2012 16:53:24:727 SWAP INF] {hap=11A7:app=Microsoft Office Excel 2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=251C:usr=V422357235}
Elapsed time for upload: 0.0 seconds


[11/01/2012 16:53:24:758 SWAP INF] {hap=11A6:app=Show Desktop 1.0:tid=1F80:usr=V47234}
Elapsed time for launch: 1.78 seconds


[11/01/2012 16:53:25:117 SWAP INF] {hap=11A6:app=Show Desktop 1.0:tid=1F80:usr=V422357235}
App shut down



[11/01/2012 10:45:00:576 ???? INF] {tid=1650}
An error occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A
ElapR
The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL 'RTSP://SRVW23E:554/V1321_BDP_V1_R1_SB/V1321_BDP_C1_P2PM_SS.sft' (rc 1690900A-00002002, 

original rc 1690900A-00002002).


[11/01/2012 00:29:59:843 OSDF ERR] {tid=1464}
The Application Virtualization Client could not parse the OSD file 'C:\SoftCache\SoftGrid Client\OSD Cache\edCc4305-3f6C-4dcc-3d70-404eb8bd97d8.osd'. Reason: 

XML parsing failure (rc 00000A25-00000002)

[11/01/2012 08:24:35:869 ???? ERR] {tid=336C:usr=t405230}
corrupt cp file detected ('V:\V1321_BDP\osguard.cp'). osguard cp file, NO CORRECTIVE ACTION TAKEN


[11/01/2012 22:16:39:240 JGSW ERR] {hap=1C82:app=bDP c15 E2AM SS 1.0:tid=3D58}
The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL 'RTSP://PSWQAPP1:554/V14678993_BDP_C15_E2AM_SS/V14678993_BDP_C15_E2AM_SS.sft' (rc 

1690900A-00002002, original rc 1690900A-00002002).


[11/01/2012 22:16:39:240 SWAP ERR] {hap=1C82:app=bDP c15 E2AM SS 1.0:tid=3D58}
The client was unable to connect to an Application Virtualization Server (rc 1690900A-00002002)


[11/01/2012 22:17:09:163 AMGR ERR] {tid=4F54}
The specified application name (Application Integration) is ambiguous. Some potential matches:
Application Integration 7.0.1756.1756
Application Integration 9.2.2373.2373


[11/01/2012 22:17:09:163 AMGR ERR] {tid=4F54}
The Application Virtualization Client cannot open Application Integration

[11/01/2012 00:03:14:313 SWAP WRN] {tid=507C:usr=N28712}
Could not load OSD file \\PSWQAPP1\Content\D1311_bDP_Adobe_Reader_9.3.3\D1311_bDP_Adobe_Reader 9.3.3.osd


[11/01/2012 00:03:14:313 AMGR INF] {tid=507C:usr=i435145}
The app manager could not create an application from '\\PSWQAPP1\Content\D1311_bDP_Adob_dobe_Reader_9.3.3\D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe Reader 9.3.3.osd' (rc 

0C405664-00000002).


====

[11/01/2012 13:35:16:987 JGSW ERR] {hap=1:app=Abaculus 1.0.0.1:tid=14C8:usr=R3R7DF42}
The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL 'RTSP:%SFT_SRV

%:554/D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe_Abaculus_15_01/D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe_Abaculus_15_01.sft' (rc 19D02E0A-10000002, original rc 19D02E0A-10000002).


[11/01/2012 13:35:47:998 SWAP ERR] {hap=2:app=AboutPI-SDK 1.3.0.26:tid=1568:usr=I337721}
Could not load app
[11/01/2012 16:53:25:399 SWAP INF] {hap=11A7:app=Microsoft Office Excel 2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=251C:usr=V47234}
Elapsed time for launch: 0.891 seconds

[11/02/2012 10:43:37:527 SWAP INF] {hap=1510:app=Adobe Reader X 10.0.1.434:tid=2AE8:usr=V47234}
App shut down


[11/02/2012 10:44:00:793 SWAP INF] {hap=1511:app=Microsoft Office Word 2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=1D80:usr=V422357235}
Elapsed time for upload: 0.0 seconds


[11/02/2012 10:44:03:809 SWAP INF] {hap=1511:app=Microsoft Office Word 2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=1D80:usr=V422357235}
Elapsed time for launch: 3.172 seconds


[11/02/2012 10:44:15:965 SWAP INF] {hap=1511:app=Microsoft Office Word 2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=1D80:usr=V422357235}
App shut down


[11/02/2012 10:44:20:637 SWAP INF] {hap=1512:app=Microsoft Office Word 2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=3B9C:usr=V47234}
Elapsed time for upload: 0.0 seconds


[11/02/2012 10:44:23:606 SWAP INF] {hap=1512:app=Microsoft Office Word 2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=3B9C:usr=V47234}
Elapsed time for launch: 3.125 seconds


[11/02/2012 10:44:32:481 SWAP INF] {hap=150B:app=Microsoft Office Excel 2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=19C:usr=V47234}
App shut down


[11/02/2012 10:44:38:575 SWAP INF] {hap=1512:app=Microsoft Office Word 2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=3B9C:usr=E831415}
App shut down


[11/02/2012 10:45:00:560 ???? INF] {tid=1650:usr=V47234}
An error occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A


[11/02/2012 10:45:00:576 ???? INF] {tid=1650}
An error occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A
ElapR
The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL 'RTSP://SRVW23E:554/V1321_BDP_V1_R1_SB/V1321_BDP_C1_P2PM_SS.sft' (rc 1690900A-00002002, 

original rc 1690900A-00002002).


[11/02/2012 00:29:59:843 OSDF ERR] {tid=1464}
The Application Virtualization Client could not parse the OSD file 'C:\SoftCache\SoftGrid Client\OSD Cache\edCc4305-3f6C-4dcc-3d70-404eb8bd97d8.osd'. Reason: 

XML parsing failure (rc 00000A25-00000002)

[11/02/2012 08:24:35:869 ???? ERR] {tid=336C:usr=t405230}
corrupt cp file detected ('V:\V1321_BDP\osguard.cp'). osguard cp file, NO CORRECTIVE ACTION TAKEN


[11/02/2012 22:16:39:240 JGSW ERR] {hap=1C82:app=bDP c15 E2AM SS 1.0:tid=3D58}
The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL 'RTSP://PSWQAPP1:554/V14678993_BDP_C15_E2AM_SS/V14678993_BDP_C15_E2AM_SS.sft' (rc 

1690900A-00002002, original rc 1690900A-00002002).


[11/02/2012 22:16:39:240 SWAP ERR] {hap=1C82:app=bDP c15 E2AM SS 1.0:tid=3D58}
The client was unable to connect to an Application Virtualization Server (rc 1690900A-00002002)


[11/02/2012 22:17:09:163 AMGR ERR] {tid=4F54}
The specified application name (Application Integration) is ambiguous. Some potential matches:
Application Integration 7.0.1756.1756
Application Integration 9.2.2373.2373


[11/02/2012 22:17:09:163 AMGR ERR] {tid=4F54}
The Application Virtualization Client cannot open Application Integration

[11/02/2012 00:03:14:313 SWAP WRN] {tid=507C:usr=N28712}
Could not load OSD file \\PSWQAPP1\Content\D1311_bDP_Adobe_Reader_9.3.3\D1311_bDP_Adobe_Reader 9.3.3.osd


[11/02/2012 00:03:14:313 AMGR INF] {tid=507C:usr=i435145}
The app manager could not create an application from '\\PSWQAPP1\Content\D1311_bDP_Adob_dobe_Reader_9.3.3\D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe Reader 9.3.3.osd' (rc 

0C405664-00000002).


====
[11/02/2012 13:35:16:987 JGSW ERR] {hap=1:app=Abaculus 1.0.0.1:tid=14C8:usr=R3R7DF42}
The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL 'RTSP:%SFT_SRV

%:554/D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe_Abaculus_15_01/D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe_Abaculus_15_01.sft' (rc 19D02E0A-10000002, original rc 19D02E0A-10000002).


[11/02/2012 13:35:47:998 SWAP ERR] {hap=2:app=AboutPI-SDK 1.3.0.26:tid=1568:usr=I337721}
Could not load app
```

I am looking to place a logic with in my script to catch the below text from the log file and output to a file with the computer Name and error message. Below are key errors in the “CoreAPP.txt“ file; if any found in current date there is something wrong and I need to fix Manually.

The main aim of the script is to report the below errors if **found on current date log text** in  the “CoreAPP.txt“ file.

> ```
> The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream
> XML parsing failure (rc 00000A25-00000002)
> corrupt cp file detected
> The client was unable to connect
> Virtualization Client cannot open Application Integration
> Could not load OSD file
> ```

**Below is my script:**

```
option Explicit

dim Fso, InFile, out, strComputer, today, strFilePath, InputFile, strLine

Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set InFile = fso.OpenTextFile("list.txt", ForReading,False,TriStateTrue)

Set out = fso.CreateTextFile("error.log")

 today = Date()

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3

const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

    Do While Not (InFile.AtEndOfStream)
      strComputer = InFile.ReadLine

      Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
         strFilePath = "\\" & strComputer & "\d$\LOGFILES\"

     Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strFilePath & "CoreAPP.txt", ForReading,False,TriStateTrue)
      Do While Not (InputFile.AtEndOfStream)
      strLine = InputFile.ReadLine

     if InStr (strLine, today) = 0 Then ' in the log file if text found with today date then it should read from there and look for any of below 6 texts

        If InStr(strLine, "corrupt cp file detected") > 0 Then

        'Kindly help me to integrate below 6 with in this script
                  '1. The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream
              '2. XML parsing failure (rc 00000A25-00000002)
              '3. corrupt cp file detected
              '4. The client was unable to connect
              '5. Virtualization Client cannot open Application Integration
              '6. Could not load OSD file

          out.WriteLine strLine & vbTab & strComputer

        End If
      End If

        Loop
      InputFile.close

    Loop

    out.Close
    InFile.Close
```

The above script will reads the computers information from list.txt file.

**Sample of list.txt**

```
Server1
server2
server3
```

*CoreAPP.txt file will be there on above (list.txt) servers. And the Path is D:\ LOGFILES \CoreAPP.txt*

The problem with the current script is, script looking for entire file, instead of current date (today is 11/2/2012 but my script checking and giving the output of 11/1/2012 &  10/31/2012  also). I mean the script writing output with regardless of Date check, this resulting output with past date and current date text in the error.log.

looking for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `instr` function always returns 0 (so the condition becomes true), because you test `date()` that is in the format `10-31-2012` to a string like [10/31/2012 08:24:35:869 ???? ERR].

Enhancements:

1. You need format you date properly
2. You need to test for <> 0

I'd suggest to capture and format the date from a dotnet stringbuilder like

```
today = createobject("System.Text.StringBuilder").AppendFormat("[{0:dd/MM/yyyy} ", Date()).ToString()
```

which will automatically prepend the `[` and append a space on the string. Now you can test if the string contains todays date by using the instr correctly. Since the string is found from the first character, I would test it like:

```
If InStr (strLine, today) = 1 Then
```

Comment: After adding above also it is not checking current date errors.. it is simply exiting out....

Comment: If i change If InStr (strLine, today) = 0 Then

Then it is showing for all the dates... so Still Logic is missing :(.. Please help me out

Comment: @Hun, Try to find out what the [InStr function](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_instr.asp) does, and you'll understand why testing on `InStr(strLine, today) = 0` always returns `True`.